# How can I implement `set field = max(1, x)` in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to update a field in a series of records with an expression that will evaluate to an integer which may be negative. I want the lower bound of the column to be 1; any rows for which the expression evaluates to less than 1 should have their field set to 1. This might be best expressed by the following pair of pseudo-SQL statements:

```
update posts set field = [expensive expression];
update posts set field = 1 where field < 1;
```

How can I implement this in a single SQL `update` statement? Is there some equivalent to `max(a, b)` in PostgreSQL, to which I can pass `max([expression], 1)`?

Comment: In the general case, a conditional (`?:` in C) is represented by `CASE` in SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the function [`GREATEST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST).

Or, a more general approach for conditions:

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN condition 
     THEN valueForTrue
     ELSE valueForFalse
     END
FROM ...
```

Comment: I don't think `CASE` is good here at all. That can involve recalculation of the expensive expression. There is no guarantee that its appearance in the `condition` and as one of the values will be optimized away; indeed, I doubt it will be.

Comment: @Andrew I said as a more general approach, not necessarily for his situation. Also you may do a single evaluation if you assign to a variable inside the *condition*, but I don't know how that is done in PostgreSQL (I'm a MySQL guy).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `GREATEST([expensive expr], 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GREATEST(1, [your expression])`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN15582).